# Using Macros to scan .odt file in libreoffice for specific content

Tags: libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-writer

Total beginner here when it comes to macros in Libreoffice.
Let's say I have a text (.odt or .doc) that contains words (irrelevant) and two types of information. The information always starts with a "/". Information type 1 looks like /234hdf (numbers and letters) and information type 2 like /02395, so only numbers.

I want to use a script that filters for type 1 information and returns it.
Is using a macro the correct way to filter for this? If so, what language should I use and where do I start?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to do with the result? Please [edit] your question and add an example of (simple) input and output. -- Please note that SO is not a good place to ask how to learn programming. There are much better suitable sites, like beginner's forums and so on. SO is meant to be a high quality question-and-answer site for. You might want to repeat the [tour].

Comment: [Andrew's macro document](https://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) section 7.14 shows how to use Search and Replace in Writer.